# Video not playing after compressing video in Android(kotlin) app using AbedElazizShe / LightCompressor Library

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile, mobile-development

I want to compress the video selected by user in my app.
For this i found this library https://github.com/AbedElazizShe/LightCompressor which makes video compressing easier
The problem i am facing is that after compressing the Video the video is not playing in any Media player like VLC etc.
The App which given in library, when i downloaded the code and run that app its working fine in that but same when i integrated in my app its not working

Comment: We have absolutely no way of knowing of what isn't working and why. If there are crashes, post the stacktrace. If the video is not loaded or shown, check if the video is corrupted. The community can help if there's more info. Since this is also related to an external open sourced library, it is better to either browse through the issue tracker or file one.